# Button is not clickable with span tag inside div tag

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, automated-tests, ui-automation

I tried to click the "No" button using the below xpath.

```
.//*[@id='btnID']
```

HTML code :

```
<div class = "ui-dialog-buttonpane" type = "button" id ="btnID">
<span class = "ui-button-text"></span>
<span class = "ui-button-text">No</span>
</div>
```

It didn't work.

But I tried with

```
.//*[@id='btnID']/span/span[1].
```

It worked fine. But my problem is div tag represents the button element. Therefore ,
    .//*[@id='btnID']
 should be also worked.

Please anyone can explain ?.

Comment: are you sure about that second path?  I don't see a span within a span.  I think that perhaps you may want to specify .//div[@id='btnID']

Comment: Yes .. It is correct.

Comment: try using .//div[@id='btnID'] instead of .//*[@id='btnID']

Comment: Really , that approach is not working .

Answer (score 0):

Here is the xpath which can Identify the object

`//div[@id='btnID']/span[.='No']`